# Regex to add <span> as child of an anchor tag w/attributes

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-code

I need a regex to find and insert anchor tags with a span child.
e.g.

replace:

```
<a
            href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Seymour,_1st_Duke_of_Somerset"
            title="Edward Seymour, 1st Duke of Somerset"
            >Edward Seymour, 1st Duke of Somerset</a
          >
```

with:

```
<a
            href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Seymour,_1st_Duke_of_Somerset"
            title="Edward Seymour, 1st Duke of Somerset"
            ><span>Edward Seymour, 1st Duke of Somerset</span></a
          >
```

The search will be in VS Code so there will be newlines and cr to contend with. I have gotten as close with

```
(.+?>){1}([a-z])*
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1904146

Comment: You can't reliably parse HTML with regular expressions.  Use a proper HTML parser.  See http://htmlparsing.com for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not perfect because you could possibly nest anchors within each other and regexes are bad about keeping tracking of nested contexts.  But a good 90% solution is to start by looking for <a, and save off everything up to and including the next >.  Then in a separate capturing group save everything up to and not including the next </a.  The final capturing group gets the </a, some optional whitespace, and the next closing >.

```
string.RegExpReplace("(<a[^>]+?>)(.+?)(</a[\s\r\n]*>)", "$1<span>$2</span>$3", regexOptios.SingleLine)
```

The $n entries in the replace string refer to the contents of each group that was captured. Result:

```
<a
        href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Seymour,_1st_Duke_of_Somerset"
        title="Edward Seymour, 1st Duke of Somerset"
        ><span>Edward Seymour, 1st Duke of Somerset</span></a
      >
```

Comment: Thanks. it works great when trying @ regex101.com but not in Vs Code find. only anchor tags that aren't broken up into multiple lines are found. I tried adding /r/n but no good.

Comment: There are several useful flags to set to tell regex how to behave.  The behavior you are describing is when the multi-line flag (/m) is set to True.  Make sure it is False so it will capture newlines as part of the dot specifier.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how you would do that. i tried adding /m to end of expression and then got no results.

Comment: I found documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-5.0.   Try calling it this way regex.replace(string,"(<a[^>]+?>)(.+?)(</a\s*>)", "$1<span>$2</span>$3",regexOptions.SingleLine)